# Recursive call with Generic method in Java

Tags: java, generics, recursion

I am working on legacy code like below

```
public Map myMethod(Map arg){
      Map newMap = createMap(); //This method creates a new Map instance.
      Iterator entries = arg.entrySet().iterator();
      while (entries.hasNext()) {
          Entry thisEntry = (Entry) entries.next();
          Object key = thisEntry.getKey();
          Object value = thisEntry.getValue();

          if ( value instanceof Map){
               Map newElement = myMethod((Map)value); // Recursive call here
               newMap.put(key, newElement);
          }else if ( value instanceof String ){
               newMap.put(key, value);
          }
      }
      return newMap;
}
```

Obviously, I would like to adapt Generics. So I changed the method like,

```
public <K,V> Map<K,V> myMethod(Map<K,V> arg){
      Map<K,V> newMap = createMap(); //creates a new Map instance.
      for ( Entry<K,V> entry : arg.entrySet()){

          K key = entry.getKey();
          V value = entry.getValue();

          if ( value instanceof Map){
               V newElement = myMethod(value); // Recursive call here
               newMap.put(key, newElement);
          }else if ( value instanceof String ){
               newMap.put(key, value);
          }
      }
      return newMap;
}
```

My question is about the line of recursive calls. So far, I have tried

1. `V newElement = myMethod(value);` -> Compile Error
2. `Map<K,V> newElement = myMethod(value);` ->compile Error
3. `V newElement = (V) myMethod((Map<?,?>)value);` ->Type safety warning

--------- Edited ----------

The further assumption that I could make is

1. createMap() method could be changed to createMap(arg)
2. Element type of arg is not bounded to a specific Java type. This is a library method so it has to be generic

Comment: Are you sure that `value` is a `Map` of the right type? Then just cast to that type and ignore the warnings.

Comment: Problem is that `V` can be either `String` or `Map<K,V>` recursing itself. `Map<K, Object>` would work, and you would need the cast (with the safety warning, nothing can be done against that)

Comment: side note: your legacy code does not compile here : `Map newElement = myMethod(value);` because `value` is an object, not a `Map`

Comment: @njzk2 I edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The logic of your code is not type-safe, so it's not possible to avoid a type-safety warning.

You create a new map using `createMap()`; that method is creating a new map blindly, with no information, so the class of map it creates is not necessarily the same as the class of `arg` that is passed in. That means your method `myMethod()` returns a map that is not necessarily of the same implementing class as the one that is passed in.

In your recursive call, you pass a map that we know is an instance of `V` into the recursive call, and you want the thing you get back out to be a `V`. But that is not necessarily true. For example, what if `V` were `TreeMap`, and the thing that is returned from the recursive call is a `HashMap`? Then it should not be able to cast to `V`, and there is no way you can safely get a `V` from that.

Comment: Make sense. Assuming I change createMap() to the createMap(arg) which returns a new instance of given argument, would this method be type safe and I could enforce generics?

Comment: @exiter2000: It would be safer. But even if you change the signatures of the methods, I'm not sure you can avoid unchecked casts.

Answer (score -1):

Your types are all messed up here.

Your method takes a

```
Map<K,V>
```

and returns a

```
Map<K,V>
```

That means the call

```
V newElement = myMethod(element);
```

must be

```
Map<K,V> newElement = myMethod(element);  //element is of type Map<K,V>
```

and the call

```
newMap.put(key, newElement);
```

means that newElement must also be of type V.

So you basically need String, Map, and V to all have some common super type. In the original code, Map is really

```
Map<Object, Object>
```

so the super type is Object.

I would back up, and ask yourself why you have a map that is storing both Maps and Strings. You should probably refactor them into objects that actually represent their types.

For instance, let's say it's a file system and the Map is a directory and the String is a File, then you should really create a FileObject that can be either a directory or a file, and your method signature becomes:

```
Map<K, FileObject> myMethod(Map<K, FileObject> map)
```

Comment: Since this method is used by other applications(over 100 calls made to this method) and it is sort of a library method, I cannot change the nature of heterogeneous elements.  This is actually simplified version of the original method. The argument Map takes Integer, List, Double, Map as elements.

Comment: Then generics won't really help you here.

You need to cast, and it will be unchecked and give a warning. The compiler can't know beforehand if V is really the right type.